# sending a php object from a php file with html to another php file

Tags: php, html, ajax

**profiles_info.php**

I have a php document that receives information from Ajax. I then set that information as attributes to an object of class Profile. I have html that displays a table. When the user clicks on Add the object should be sent to add_to_database.php where I want to access all of the objects attributes.

```
    $firstName = $_POST['fn'];
    $lastName = $_POST['ln'];

    class Profile{  
        public $firstName;
        public $lastName;


        public function setFirstName($fn){
            $this->firstName = $fn;
        }

        public function setLastName($ln){
            $this->lastName = $ln;
        }

        public function getFirstName(){
            return $this->firstName; 
        }

        public function getLastName(){
            return $this->lastName;
        }

    }

    $person = new Profile();

    $person->setFirstName($firstName);
    $person->setLastName($lastName);


    echo "<p><table border= \"1\"><tr><th> First Name:</th><th> Last Name:</th><th> Add To Database:</th></tr><tr><td>" . $person->getFirstName() . "</td><td>" . $person->getLastName() . "</td><td><a href='add_to_database.php'>Add</a></td></tr></table></p> ";
```

How do I  send the firstname and lastname to add_to_database.php?

I have tried include, but the html appears. I have also tried sessions by storing the $person object in a session but I don't know how to access getFirstName and getLastName in add_to_database.php. The $person object will have more attributes later so i don't want to store every single attribute in a session. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Share your object using sessions as you said , and use your getters like in your local file , but , include you class file and cast it

Comment: So add some database code. Since you haven't shown any of this `add_to_database.php` script, we can't help you. None of the code you've shown even REMOTELY involves a database.

Comment: @MarcB He just wants to get the call to that file. He's not asking how to code once it's there.

Comment: You can AJAX betweem php files. You can actually just send it directly to add_to_database.php from wherever your other ajax call is

Comment: How can i also send it to add_to_database.php at the same time. I'm new to AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i suggest is to `serialize` your object and put it in a session variable ,and in your seconde page  `unserialize` it and call your get methodes.

Example :

```
$person = new Profile();
$s = serialize($person);
$_SESSION['mySerializedObject']=$s;
```

And in your seconde page :

```
include 'Profile Class file here';

$u = unserialize($_SESSION['mySerializedObject']);
echo $u->getFirstname();
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but if i use include  my html appears on add_to_database.php also it gives out errors since it does not recognize the POST objects in profiles_info.php. $person->getFirstName() is not retrieving anything.

Comment: it's a better to put you class definition in a separate file